# Questions (beta)

Tags: youtube-api

I'm a professor and want to start making several short micro-lessons with embedded questions for my students to test their knowledge along the way. I've been researching some new Youtube beta features "Questions" and "Linking my Youtube Channel with my website (google site, google+, etc)

1. I had access to the beta "Questions" option a few days ago and it's gone now. I can edit existing annotation which includes a true/false question I added, but I can no longer see the option to add new question. Can you help me?
2. Can set up questions within the video that have a definite correct answer vs incorrect, and then sort through analytics to see how viewers did?
3. Is there a way to have different outcomes for viewers depending on whether they answered correctly (congratulations screen) vs incorrectly(rewind and replay a section of the video, then repeat question)?
4. Is there a way for viewers who complete the video and answer correctly to forward a "Congratulations screen" to their instructors for possible credit on assignments?
5. Lastly, Is there a way to integrate Google presentation with YouTube video (e.g.create slideshow in "presentation" for easier conversion to video w/ voice)?    Right now I use a three step process: 1) create presentation in PPT,  2) voiceover the slides and make a video in "Captivate",  then 3) upload to Youtube.
   Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that your question, as asked, has to do with the YouTube API.

That being said, we do have this blog post and tutorial video up for an open source project that integrates YouTube video content with quiz content: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/06/google-io-tutorials-using-ruby-on-rails.html

Comment: Agreed that it isn't an API question, but might also be helpful to note that the questions editor is an opt-in beta, and the opt-in flag sometimes gets reset for a user's account ... can always opt in again here: http://www.youtube.com/video_questions_beta to get access to the questions editor again.